# Silverstripe: link to correct I18N URL from footer template

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe

My website has two languages and I have a problem with the footer links.

Before my redesign I included different files. One with links pointing to /en/privacy/ or /en/contact/ etc. and another file with links like /datenschutz/ or /kontakt/

```
<% if Locale == en_GB %>
  <% include Footer_en_GB %>
<% else %>
  <% include Footer %>
<% end_if %>
```

That makes it hard to maintain.

Is there a better way? IS it possible to get the propper I18N link for a page?

Something like

```
<a href="i18nlink('/datenschutz/')">i18ntitle('/datencshutz/')</a>
```

so the EN footer will look like

```
<a href="/en/privacy/">Privacy</a>
```

and the DE footer will look like

```
<a href="/datenschutz/">Datenschutz</a>
```

Comment: You could try using a module like [`silverstripe-fluent`](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent) for this

Comment: I don't know fluent, but I'll have look at it. Currently I am stuck to Translatable

Comment: How do you specify the pages that are linked to in the footer? Do you just add them in the template markup? I usually have these editable in the SiteConfig section, this makes it also really easy to specify the footer links per language…

Comment: Mostly I put them into the template, because there is more complicated HTML for modals, forms, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Translatable Module](https://packagist.org/packages/silverstripe/translatable) and the Pages are actually Linked in the CMS, you can simply use `$Link?Locale=en_US` or rather `/datenschutz/?Locale=en_US`.
When you then visit `/datenschutz/?Locale=en_US`, SilverStripe will response with a redirect to the EN Link.

Or in PHP, you can use:

```
if ($page->hasTranslation('en_US')) {
    $link = $page->getTranslation('en_US')->Link();
}
```

PS: this gist might also interest you: https://gist.github.com/Zauberfisch/9226142#file-translatablecontrollerextension-php-L39

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have clean links, no ?locale added. The PHP code doesn't help either. I need something to output either the default URL (German) or – based on the current locale – the Englisch one. Anyhow, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I thought there is some simple solution built in SS, but couldn't find any.

Here is what I have done now

Template:

```
<ul class="vertical menu">
    <li><a href="$LanguageURL('homepage')">Startseite</a></li>
    <li><a href="$LanguageURL('unternehmen')">Über uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="$LanguageURL('kontakt')">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Necessary code in mysite/code/page.php (inside the Page class):

```
public function LanguageURL($page) {
    if (empty($page)) {
        $page = $this;
    } else {
        $SQL_url = Convert::raw2sql($page);
        $page = Translatable::get_one_by_lang('SiteTree', 'de_DE', "URLSegment = '$SQL_url'");
    }

    if ($page->hasTranslation('en_GB') && Translatable::get_current_locale() == 'en_GB') {
        $link = $page->getTranslation('en_GB')->Link();
    } else {
        $link = $page->getTranslation('de_DE')->Link();
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Your German website outputs

```
    <li><a href="/kontakt/">Kontakt</a></li>
```

… and your English website outputs

```
    <li><a href="/en/contact/">Contact</a></li>
```

Actual output depends on your config, but the point is to output the proper URL for the current locale.

Perhaps anybody needs something similar or has a better solution :-)

Comment: this only works until someone changes the urlsegment accidently :(